# Why does continue print a number even when the loop has left that number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

Why does number 4 get printed even when the loop is on 5.

```
a = 1
while a < 10:
    a = a + 1
    if a < 4:
        continue
    if a > 6:
        break
    print(a)
```

Comment: `4<4 = False` THis is why this happens

Comment: Why 4 wouldn't be printed ? at `a = 3` you skip the print with `continue`. Then when `a = 4`, none of the conditions are True, so it is printed, same as `a = 5` and `a = 6`. The loop is finally canceled when `a = 7` with `break` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The number 4 is being printed because it doesn't fit the condition `a<4` since 4 is not less than 4.

If you want the number 4 not to be printed, you can use `if a <= 4:` or `if a < 5:`.

Comment: Jup, that's pretty much it

Answer (score 1):

Because you have used condition `if a < 4:` which will be used for the values which are less than 4 but not for 4. To not print 4, you should use less than or equal (<=) instead of less(<) sign.

```
a = 1
while a < 10:
    a = a + 1
    if a <= 4:
        continue
    if a > 6:
        break
    print(a)
```

This above code will use `continue` statement till `a=4` print the values 5 and 6. If you wants only 5 to be printed out then you can use `if a >= 6:` instead of `if a > 6:`.

Answer (score 1):

Cause you set conditions for numbers from (-inf,3) to (7,9) but the numbers 4, 5 and 6 that don't have any restrictions get printed.